# How to write to host a list of unique results from a for each loop in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In the following code, I am getting a list of duplicate values. I am trying to have only one line for each duplicated lines, distinct.

This is the code:

```
# Find DC list from Active Directory
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *

# Define time for report (default is 1 day)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified dates and workstation/IP in an array
foreach ($DC in $DCs){
$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC.HostName  -after $startDate -InstanceId 4624 | where {$_.ReplacementStrings[5].ToLower() -eq "administrator"}

# Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time, status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely

  foreach ($e in $slogonevents){            
    if ($e.EventID -eq 4624 -and $e.ReplacementStrings[8] -In 3..10){            
      if([ipaddress]::TryParse($e.ReplacementStrings[18],[ref][ipaddress]::Loopback))
      {
        $type = $e.ReplacementStrings[8]
        $ip = $e.ReplacementStrings[18]
        $hostname=([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip)).HostName

        write-host "Type:" $type "`tIP Address: " $ip  "`tHost Name: " $hostname             
      }
    }
  }
} Get-Unique #this does not work, also tried Unique
```

I am getting an output similar to the following"

```
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.1 Host Name: ABCD
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.1 Host Name: ABCD
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.1 Host Name: ABCD
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.2 Host Name: EFGH
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.2 Host Name: EFGH
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.2 Host Name: EFGH
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.1 Host Name: ABCD
```

I would like to get:

```
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.1 Host Name: ABCD
Type: 3  IP Address: 192.168.1.2 Host Name: EFGH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you are not getting unique values is you are writing to host in your `foreach` loop, prior to the `Unique`. Essentially writing them out before it knows what is `unique`

What I would do is create a `PSCustomObject` and assign it within your `foreach`. This would allow you to call it later using `| Select -Unique`

```
# Find DC list from Active Directory
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *

# Define time for report (default is 1 day)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified dates and workstation/IP in an array
foreach ($DC in $DCs){
$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security  -after $startDate -InstanceId 4624 | where {$_.ReplacementStrings[5].ToLower() -eq "administrator"}

# Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time, status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely

  foreach ($e in $slogonevents){  
     $report = @() 
    if ($e.EventID -eq 4624 -and $e.ReplacementStrings[8] -In 3..10){            
      if([ipaddress]::TryParse($e.ReplacementStrings[18],[ref][ipaddress]::Loopback))
      {
        $object = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
            type = $e.ReplacementStrings[8]
            ip = $e.ReplacementStrings[18]
            hostname=([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($($e.ReplacementStrings[18]))).HostName        
        }
        $report += $object
      }
    }
  }
}
$report | select -Unique
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I have improved it a little more by moving the $report = @() line to the first for loop in case it will be duplication with DCs. You could fix it in your answer.

Comment: Moved it inside the `foreach`

Comment: As per my understanding, you should remove $ip from GetHostByAddress($ip)).HostName since ip variable is not yet created at this stage

Comment: Good catch. I updated it to look it up by `$e.ReplacementSTrings[18]`